# Relate Table1 to table2 and show a field from table2 on table1

Tags: database, excel

I need to be able to relate table1 to table2 based on an ID value each table shares. If ID from table1 = ID from table2 I want to show a date value from table2 on table1.

If someone can help me that would be great.

Comment: How we will help you? Where is your data?

Comment: `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX MATCH` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Vlookup should work for you:

Use VLOOKUP, one of the lookup and reference functions, when you need to find things in a table or a range by row. For example, look up a price of an automotive part by the part number.

In its simplest form, the VLOOKUP function says:

=VLOOKUP(Value you want to look up, range where you want to lookup the value, the column number in the range containing the return value, Exact Match or Approximate Match – indicated as 0/FALSE or 1/TRUE).

```
=VLOOKUP('IDINTABLE1,RANGEINTABLE2,COLUMNWHEREISTHEVALUEINTABLE2,0)
```

This should work.

Comment: For some reason this doesnt work when the range and value im looking up are in a separate sheet in an excel workbook

Comment: It should work if you have the two excel files open in the same instance. Can you paste your files here?